# IR2101 cross-conduction

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

The [IR2101](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir2101.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c7a755166c) is an high and low driver typically used to drive MOSFET half bridges.

On [this blog](http://tahmidmc.blogspot.fr/2013/01/using-high-low-side-driver-ir2110-with.html), it is said (IR2110 is almost the same as IT2101):

> "IR2110 can't be used to drive both high-side and low-side MOSFETs simultaneously"

The only indication about that specific point I can find in the datasheet is the sentence:

> "The output drivers feature a high pulse current buffer stage designed
>   for minimum driver cross-conduction"

However the functional block diagram doesn't mention any exclusion of the HIN+LIN case, and they also show examples where HIN and LIN are switching from low to high simultaneously.

So, do you think I can cross-conduct my half-bridge by setting both pins to high with this driver?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing this driver format with one that would have oppossing outputs? (eg.: One non-inverted and one inverted).

Comment: Actually I think I have my answer, if you have a look at the ir2104 datasheet, you can clearly see that there is a deadtime mentionned while it doesnt appear at all on the ir2101

Comment: This is because the ir2104 has opposing HI/LO signals with only one input signal, (and a shut down).  It is meant to be used with a common mosfet load output (hence the need for a dead time).  The ir2101 is more flexibility with each driver controlled separately. To use the ir2101 as one side of a full bridge or as a half bridge driver you would need to have separate input signals and provide the required dead time. Finally note the differences in the typical connection diagrams of both parts, there is a reason the ir2101 version shows two load outputs while the ir2104 version only shows one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can count on the matched output delay times within 10 ns for the IR2101 using the test circuit and test method in the datasheet.

Putting both inputs high would pull both outputs high , which is the same as shorting out your load to the same supply voltage.  ( i.e. Brake )

External drivers can then be modified to control the Dead Time to prevent shootthru with L/R decay times using non-linear Diode/R ratios with Ciss.

**Measurement Thresholds**  ( Note the different threshold levels)
[image]

The deadtime can be improved with the (R1//D3,R2//D2 ;)) Diode shunted 10 Ohm R to turn Off faster than On.. The diode has low resistance (~1 ohm)during rapid negative edge Vgs transitions.

[image]